# Proving a version of the Kronecker's Theorem

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, topological-groups

I am trying to prove the following version of the Kronecker's Theorem:

> Suppose $k$ is a positive integer and $\{1, \theta_0, \dots, \theta_{k-1}\}$ is linearly independent over $\mathbb Q$. Then $\{(n\theta_0+\mathbb Z, \dots, n\theta_{k-1} + \mathbb Z): n \in \mathbb Z\}$ is dense in $T^k$ (where $T$ is the group $\mathbb R /\mathbb Z$ with the natural quotient topology).

I am trying to prove this by induction. I have already proven the case $k=1$ but I don't know what to do in the case $k+1$.

Comment: If you know about measure theory, prove instead that the sequence is uniformly distributed (this implies denseness). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistributed_sequence

Comment: Hope you have access to a university library. Look at chapter seven of [Apostol's book](http://www.amazon.com/Modular-Functions-Dirichlet-Graduate-Mathematics/dp/0387971270#reader_0387971270). I waded through that proof as an undergrad, and I thought it was kinda sleek. IIRC not using induction on $k$ though. The two-dimensional case can still be done by staring long and hard at pictures, but I don't know about higher dimensions.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Sadly, I don't have the background to understand a prove that uses equidistributed sequence.

Comment: Jyrki, you could post your comment as an answer. I took a look at this book and I am happy with it.